# How to install firewall script in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Router/Firewall

In the link above there is a firewall script described. How can I install this script in Ubuntu 10.0.4 desktop?

Comment: IPTables is already in ubuntu 10.04.  Try "iptables" from command line.

Comment: your question is appropriate for both SU and SF, but don't [post it to both](http://superuser.com/questions/184540/how-to-install-firewall-script-in-ubuntu) unless you've had no reply for a while (more than a few hours), and if you do, link to the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A hacky way to do it would be to place the script somewhere on the file system and then run it from /etc/init.d/rc.local.

Usually I manage Ubuntu firewalls with an iptables script in /etc, and then add something as outlined here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo#Solution%20#1%20-%20/etc/network/interfaces

Comment: do you use NetworkManager to run the iptables scripts?